# Flutter-ListView overflow

Tags: android, listview, flutter

[Flutter Overflow widget picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BufZ.jpg)

I want to design a ListView of widgets, each widget has a container which stores the information. I try to use ListView but the containers don't appear on the screen so I switched to Row, they appear but they cannot exceed the maximum width of the containers. Can you suggest how to manage a ListView in the picture?
Here is My Code:

```
class NewsPage extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

Widget buildButtonScore= Container(

  height: 100.0,
  width: 100.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),color: Colors.white),
  child: FlatButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
    child: Column( // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline,size: 30.0,color: Colors.blue),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => PointPage()
                  )
              );
            }
        ),
        Text("Đặt hàng",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
Widget buildButtonOrder= Container(
  height: 100.0,
  width: 100.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),color: Colors.white),
  child: FlatButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
    child: Column( // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart,size: 30.0,color: Colors.blue),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => PointPage()
                  )
              );
            }
        ),
        Text("Đặt hàng",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
Widget buildButtonPurse = Container(
  height: 100.0,
  width: 100.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),color: Colors.white),
  child: FlatButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
    child: Column( // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.monetization_on,size: 30.0,color: Colors.blue),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => PointPage()
                  )
              );
            }
        ),
        Text("Ví tiền",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
//Button Column
Widget buttonRow = Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      buildButtonScore,
      buildButtonOrder,
      buildButtonPurse,
    ],
  ),
);
//OFFERROW
Widget offer1 = Container(
  height: 150.0,
  width: 180.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),color: Colors.white30),
  child: FlatButton(

    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),

    child: Column( 

      children: <Widget>[

        new Image.asset('images/Q.png',height: 90.0,fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,width: 180.0,),

        Text("Các cô gái đẹp đang chờ bạn đó!!!",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
Widget offer2 = Container(
  height: 150.0,
  width: 180.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),color: Colors.white30),
  child: FlatButton(

    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),

    child: Column( // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text

      children: <Widget>[
        new Image.asset('images/Nina.gif',height: 90.0,fit:BoxFit.fitWidth,width: 180.0,),

        Text("Hãy nhanh tay sở hữu vé xem phim Goddess Kiss!",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
Widget offerRow = Row(
  //shrinkWrap: true,
  //scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: <Widget>[
    Row(
      children: [
        offer1,
        VerticalDivider(),
        offer2,
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

Widget newsRow = Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
    height: 125.0,
    child: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      children: <Widget>[
        new NewsBody(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
// TODO: implement build
return Container(
  child: ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children: <Widget>[
      buttonRow,

      new Text('Dành cho bạn',style: TextStyle( fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),),
      offerRow,

      new Text('Tin tức',style: TextStyle( fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),),
      newsRow,
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

}

I get the error:

[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oUDj.png)

[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL4Fq.png)

[Pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yoI9.png)

[Pic4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd6f5.png)

[Pic5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ieJI.png)

Comment: what happen if you use listview in horizontal mode? what error do you get?

Comment: Can you put some code?

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian I added the code.

Comment: @diegoveloper I updated the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add your code inside SingleChildScrollView with scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, or replace with below code

```
Widget offerRow = new SingleChildScrollView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
child: Row(
  //shrinkWrap: true,
  //scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: <Widget>[
    Row(
      children: [
        offer1,
        VerticalDivider(),
        offer2,
      ],
    ),
  ],
),);
```