# Flutter - How to make a column screen scrollable

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm building a flutter app with a Login Screen. On focus on the text field(s), the screen is overflowed and i cannot scroll. I've tried using a `ListView.builder`, but that just gives a renderBox error, and the regular `ListView` doesn't work

[image: Screen]
[image: Screen on Text Input]

The widget structure is like this

```
-scafold
   - body
     - container
       - column    
           - form
              - column
                  - textInput
                  - textInput
                  - container    
           - container
              - row      
           - raisedButton
```

Thank You in advance !!

Comment: use this reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997936/flutter-listview-overflow/51998850#51998850

Comment: I replaced the first column with a ListView and it worked. If you prefer using Listview, please add the example with listview and paste the error here. otherwise, use @Zulfiqar 's way

Answer (score 98, accepted):

try this Code: Its Using ListView

```
    class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement build
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 8.0,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                              labelText: "Username or Email",
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15.0,
                          ),
                          TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                              labelText: "Password",
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15.0,
                          ),
                          Material(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                            //elevation: 5.0,
                            child: MaterialButton(
                              onPressed: () => {},
                              minWidth: 150.0,
                              height: 50.0,
                              color: Color(0xFF179CDF),
                              child: Text(
                                "LOGIN",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(child: Text("Don't Have a Account?")),
                    Text("Sign Up",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      color: Colors.white,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                            32.0,
                          ),
                          side: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF179CDF))),
                      child: Text(
                        "SKIP SIGN UP FOR NOW",
                        style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Color(0xFF179CDF)),
                      ),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: `shrinkWrap: true` is the only thing important in this exhaustive answer

Answer (score 158):

The `ListView` solution should work, but at the time of writing, it suffers from the crash listed [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31081). Another way to achieve the same thing without this crash is to use a `SingleChildScrollView`:

```dart
return new Container(
  child: new SingleChildScrollView(
    child: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _showChild1(),
        _showChild2(),
        ...
        _showChildN()
      ]
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: This method did not work for me when the column I wanted to scroll was nested inside another column.  It worked for scrolling the outermost column.

Comment: Only the first child in widget tree makes the column scroll vertically. I want to make make the entire items scrolls

Comment: I you encounter few error try adding ``` mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min  ``` to your ```Column``` widget. Also if the child widget is  ```ListView.builde``` add  ```shrinkWrap: true```

Comment: In case you have ListView inside Column (**SingleChildScrollView** -> **Column** -> **ListView**) it is better to add to `ListView` `shrinkWrap: true` and `physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics()`

Answer (score 88):

There are two easy ways of doing it.

1. Wrap your `Column` in a `SingleChildScrollView`

   ```
   SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Column(
       children: [
         Text('First'),
         //... other children
         Text('Last'),
       ],
     ),
   )
   ```
2. Use `ListView` instead of `Column`.

   ```
   ListView(
     children: [
       Text('First'),
       //... other children
       Text('Last'),
     ],
   )
   ```

   This approach is simple to use, but you lose features like `crossAxisAlignment` and other benefits provided by `Column`, in that case, you can wrap your children widget inside `Align` and set alignment property.

---

Now you may have nested children which are further scrollable, in that case, you need to provide a fixed height to your children, you may use `SizedBox` for that, that's it.

For example:

```
ListView(
  children: [
    Text('First'),
    SizedBox(
      height: 100,
      child: ListView(...), // nested ScrollView
    ),
    Text('Last'),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Most complete and easiest to follow answer for me.

Comment: Using a `SingleChildScrollView` should be the accepted and standard way of achieving this.

Comment: thanks for sharing this info. Could you tell the which one is recommended?

Comment: @Aravin Well it depends on your use case, if there aren't enough items and you want some properties of `Column` then go for it, otherwise `ListView` is better.

Comment: This is the best answer. If you have nested columns or nested ListView, defining the height of the inner Column/ListView is essential to have multiple scrolls. If you don't have a fixed size, instead of SizedBox, you can use Expanded

Answer (score 11):

We can use the Expanded widget. It will add scrolling.

```
return new Expanded(
  child: new SingleChildScrollView(
    child: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _showChild1(),
        _showChild2(),
        ...
        _showChildN()
      ]
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: The main thing here is not the Expanded but the scroll view.

Answer (score 8):

If you have nested columns, go with the solution using

```
Expanded -> SingleChildScrollView -> Column
```

Here is the solution:

```
OnboardingScaffold(
  body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ...,
                ...
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your column in SingleChildScrollView and then wrap SingleChildScrollView in a Center widget to center the widgets in the column.

```
Center(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
        children: [
            Text('First'),
            //... other children
            Text('Last'),
        ],
    ),
)
```