# How to make a Form scrollable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, scroll, scrollable

So I'm trying to make an app where I have the user fill out a couple form fields and process the information when the user submits the form. My problem is that I can't seem to find out how to make the `Form` scrollable (because it's long and causes a RenderFlex error). Any scrollable widget I wrap it with still causes a RenderFlex error. The only time it scrolls is when I wrap it with a `ListView` but it too, causes a RenderFlex error and worst of all, for some reason scrolls back to normal when I try to scroll to the bottom to hit the button to submit. I've already tried most of the solutions in [How to scroll page in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765092/how-to-scroll-page-in-flutter) and [Flutter - How to make a column screen scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053850/flutter-how-to-make-a-column-screen-scrollable), but none of them seem to work. Here's how the form is structured:

```
- Form
  - Column (List of input fields, crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.start)
   - Padding (Input field, top padding of 12)
    - Column (Text + input field)
     - Align (alignment = Alignment.centerLeft)
      - Padding (Left padding 8)
       - Text (Field title)
     - Padding (Symmetric horizontal padding of 8)
      - TextFormField (Text input)
   - Seven more input fields with the same structure (Padding > Column > Align > ...)
   - Padding (Vertical padding of 64)
    - Align (center alignment)
     - FractionallySizedBox (for 75% width)
      - SizedBox (for fixed height)
       - ElevatedButton (Submit button)
        - Text (Submit button text)
```

I hope this is enough information and I'd really appreciate if anyone could help me out with making this form scrollable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to add your `Column` inside `SingleChildScrollView` refer my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68646487/13997210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69392879/13997210) hope its help to you

Comment: Like I've said in the post, `SingleChildScrollView` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: where you put `SingleChildScrollView` ?

Comment: As the parent of the `Column` widget. It still causes the RenderFlex issue and isn't scrollable.

Comment: first thing why do have used 2 `Column`?

Comment: Wrap column in Expanded Widget

Comment: If `SingleChildScrollView` not work then used `Expanded` widget or `ListView` also

Comment: I've used a `Column` to stack all the different fields and then another `Column` inside the `Padding` widget to stack the input title and input field.

Comment: I haven't used an `Expanded` widget though…

Comment: Add all inner column in Expand Widget and Change Out side Column to ListView

Comment: Ok thanks @JasminSojitra I'll try that and let you know what happens.

Comment: One question: By inner columns do you mean columns that occur in every input field?

Comment: First, take the List view and Add One by one children which one has issue add in the Expanded widget

Comment: I just wrapped all the inner columns in `Expanded` widgets, and that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You have to give a code then we will check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245201/discussion-between-pyzard-and-jasmin-sojitra).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is when you use **Column** without specifying the height it considers the height to be infinite. Try to wrap the first column widget with **SizedBox** and make use of **MediaQuery** to determine the screen height and set it as the height parameter for **SizedBox**.

Now, wrap the **Column** with a **SingleChildScrollView** to make it scrollable.

For Example,

```
SizedBox(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Column(...),
  ),
),
```

Lastly, why do you need a second **Column** for text and input field? Can't you just use the **InputDecoration** method from **TextField()** and use the **labelText** or **HelperText**

Comment: This works! Thank you so much for the answer! I've been stuck on this problem for hours.

Comment: Also, update on the second part: I've updated the code to use `labelText` and `helperText` along with `hintText`.

Comment: Note that `SingleScrollChildView` is not syntactically correct here - it should be `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: @cmjordan yes it’s a typo. Fixed it!

Comment: What an epic commitment to accuracy for a question answered 1.5y ago! Bonus points for you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SingleChildScrollView Widget.

Comment: Like I've said in the post, `SingleChildScrollView` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SingleChildScrollView` and wrap it with a `Container` widget and provide a certain height to it.